# Multiple facets with SolrNet

Tags: solrnet

I want to do a query with two facets with SolrNet, City And Category.
But each facet has diferrent properties. For example mincount for city is zero and for category is 1.

How can I do this with SolrNet?

I know FacetParametes has Queries property that can be an array of queries, but what about mincount?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
solr.Query("something", new QueryOptions {
    Facet = new FacetParameters {
        Queries = new[] {
            new SolrFacetFieldQuery("city") { MinCount = 0 },
            new SolrFacetFieldQuery("category") { MinCount = 1 },
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how to do this dynamically... I have numbers of dynamic filter criteria. Its dynamic so I need to program it to run new SolrFacetFieldQuery for each of them dynamically... Any idea how to do this?